# Fix UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.7, unicode

I have the following code . I use Python 2.7

```
import csv
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('torrents.db')
c = conn.cursor()

# Create table
c.execute('''DROP TABLE torrents''')
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS torrents
             (name text, size long, info_hash text, downloads_count long, 
             category_id text, seeders long, leechers long)''')

with open('torrents_mini.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|')
    for row in spamreader:
        name = unicode(row[0])
        size = row[1]
        info_hash = unicode(row[2])
        downloads_count = row[3]
        category_id = unicode(row[4])
        seeders = row[5]
        leechers = row[6]
        c.execute('INSERT INTO torrents (name, size, info_hash, downloads_count, 
                   category_id, seeders, leechers) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',
                   (name, size, info_hash, downloads_count, category_id, seeders, leechers))

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

The error message I receive is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "db.py", line 15, in <module>
    name = unicode(row[0])
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 14: ordinal not in range(128)
```

If I don't convert into unicode then  the error i get is

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.
```

adding `name = row[0].decode('UTF-8')` gives me another error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "db.py", line 27, in <module>
    for row in spamreader:
_csv.Error: line contains NULL byte
```

the data contained in the csv file is in the following format

```
Tha Twilight New Moon DVDrip 2009 XviD-AMiABLE|694554360|2cae2fc76d110f35917d5d069282afd8335bc306|0|movies|0|1
```

Edit:I finally dropped the attempt and accomplished the task using sqlite3 command-line tool(it was quite easy).
I do not yet know what caused the errors , but when sqlite3 was importing the said csv file , it kept popping warnings about "unescaped character", the character being quotes(").

Thanks to everyone who tried to help.

Comment: Can you give us the **full traceback**  of the error. What is the *encoding* used in the file?

Comment: the traceback is Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "db.py", line 15, in <module>
    name = unicode(row[0])
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 14: ordinal
 not in range(128)

Comment: You need to [edit] your post to add that information. Don't stick it in a comment.

Comment: Sorry , just did that.

Comment: that sample line you included is not problematic. It is later lines that are. The most common reason you see the `NULL byte` error is when the data is encoded to UTF-16 or UTF-32, but the line you posted certainly doesn't. There still isn't enough information here to say what is going on. If decoding as UTF-8 leads to a new error, then at least you **appear** to have found a valid codec.

Comment: decoding using utf-16 and utf-32 both gives errors. If you want i can post that too.

Comment: No, no need. I already said that that was not the case **here**.

Comment: Show an example of the lines in the .csv that actually cause the errors.  Post the .csv somewhere perhaps.

Comment: The csv file is the list of torrents in the kickass website, provided to the public as a part of openbay initiative. More information and csv obatained here: http://openbay.isohunt.to/#slide4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is not encoded as ASCII. Use the correct codec for your data.

You can tell Python what codec to use with:

```
unicode(row[0], correct_codec)
```

or use the `str.decode()` method:

```
row[0].decode(correct_codec)
```

What that correct codec is, we cannot tell you. You'll have to consult whatever you got the file from.

If you cannot figure out what encoding was used, you could use a package like [`chardet`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) to make an educated guess, but take into account that such a library is not fail-proof.

Comment: I have no idea about the encoding used .